# Google Maps Cluster Display Bubble on Marker Click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am wishing to use Google Maps API V3 feature "MarkerClusterer" (http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/examples/advanced_example.html)  I have all this working and pulling in JSON data, but I am unable to get a clickable trigger on the `markers`.  Now to clarify the `clusters` are working as they should, but when you drill down into a `cluster` and see the `markers` I wish to be able to click the `marker` and display a bubble with custom information over the `marker`.

I created a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/helpinspireme/B3a86/  I have tried adding in `marker` calls to display the bubble information like http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/single-infowindow/single-infowindow.html but I have not succeeded in mixing the two.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify whether you want to display the bubble when you click the **cluster** or the **marker**. The title suggests cluster, the 1st paragraph of your question suggest marker. Then edit the question title or the text! After this the question can be upvoted.

Comment: Adjusted the title to clarify.  The `clusters` work as they should, I just wish to add the functionality that when a `marker` is clicked a bubble will display over the `marker`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you tried? Just add the InfoWindow normally [as in](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple?hl=cs) the [google basic samples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/?hl=cs) and it works!

http://jsfiddle.net/B3a86/2/

Comment: Not sure what caused the issue then, but thank you for clearing that up for me.

Comment: If I may ask you one more question.  I would like to add in some code that when a bubble is opened, for the user to be able to close the bubble when the map is clicked or another `marker` is clicked.  Right now if you click the same `marker` over and over it stacks them and if you click another `marker` they all just stay open and I would like it so only one can be open at a time.

Comment: Just a quick guess but maybe if you have the infobox as a global you can change/reposition it instead of making a new one for each marker. I haven't tried this but it's just a thought.